# New Navigation "Find questions with all tags" problem

Tags: support, new-nav

With the new navigation there is a button to search for questions with all your (and/or favourite) tags. This is a problem, something as simple as having both a `C` and `C++`. Anything like that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there. Please follow the below steps to use it.

1. **Go to new nav. Select "custom tags" in filter, hover your mouse over the tag name field. "edit" will appear.**

[image]

2. **Click on edit, key in your required tags, select "Apply".**

[image]

3. **On the RHS of the tag bar, there is option "any", the questions with *any* of the tags will appear.**

[image]

4. **There is another option "all", the questions with _all_of the tags will appear.**

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I confused Favorite and Custom.